# Does 2008 support large icons on taskbar?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Looks like there's no such option to set to large icons on taskbar (the quick launch panel),

[image]

Was it supported or if there any other trick I can do? The icons are too small.

**To whoever vote to close**

Why close this question?

It doesn't work as the same way in Windows 7, and on one ever asked similar questions

Comment: End-user options on the desktop doesn't really fall under the "professional systems administrations" remit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. First you have to unlock the task bar:

[image]

Then right-click any empty space in the quick-launch area and go to the "View" flyout. Select "Large Icons"

[image]

Ta da!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but the pic is important...because by default Windows 2008 R2 doesn't show what is shown by WesleyDavid.

Example:

[image: Windows 2008 R2 Taskbar properties]

So perhaps you should mention in your question that you were specifically referring to Windows 2008 and not the R2 version.  (Note:  I don't even have a 2008 version to test on but I'm guessing Wesley covered that correctly)